# Validate a JSON and provide a custom validation report

Tags: java, json, validation

I have an application that receives a JSON and upon receiving it should **validate** it. The validation is consisted out of several steps.

1. If the received object is a properly formatted JSON
2. If all the required fields are present
3. If all the fields constraints are satisfied (ie. string sizes)
4. If the conditional dependencies are satisfied (if some field has value A, then another field should have value B)

Based on the described requirements, if any of the constraints is violated, I should generate my own, specifically formatted, **validation report object**.

I have considered several ways how to do this, but I am not really happy with any, and hoping to get an advice from you guys, how this could be done. What I have considered:

### Idea #1: Jackson + JSR303 bean validation

```
@CustomConstraintIfAThenB // this should emulate the conditional dependency
public class Message {
    @JsonProperty(value = "a", required = true)
    @Size(min = 3, max = 8)
    private String a;

    @JsonProperty(value = "b", required = true)
    @Size(min = 5, max = 9)
    private String b;

    // ...
}
```

The problem I found with this approach is when generating my report, because first I need to use the Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to try to create my POJO. If this throws `JsonProcessingException` I should parse it, and create my report. If doesn't throw, only then I can validate with my bean validator (ie. `Hibernate`).

```
MyReport report = null;
Message m = null;

// first Jackson validation
try {
    m = objectMapper.treeToValue(json, Message.class);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    report = myExceptionParser.parse(e);
}

// second bean (field) validation
Set<ConstraintViolation<Message>> violations = validator.validate(m);
if (violations.size() > 0) {
    report = myViolationsParser.parse(violations);
}
```

Big problem with this is the actual **parsing** through the `JsonProcessingException` to create my custom report. And additionally parse through the `violations`. I should write two parsers, one of which (the one that parses the exception) would probably be extremely clumsey.

### Idea #2: Validation against JSON schema

I could write a JSON schema and then validate an incoming JSON against that schema. The up side for this is that I would have a unique, consistent report generated by the JSON Schema Validator I am using, and I should only write one parser for it. For example if I were to use [fge-validator](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator):

```
JsonSchema schema = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault().getJsonSchema(mySchema);
ProcessingReport report = mySchema.validate(json);

// only have one parser to parse the report to my custom report
MyReport = myReportParser.parse(report);
```

The problem is with this that **JSON Schema v4** gets very clumsy when dealing with conditional dependencies, as there are no IF-THEN-ELSE keywords. And I couldn't find a library that would support JSON Schema v7. Also, modifying a large JSON Schema can get tricky and very prone to errors. In that context also, class annotations would be better.

Is there any 3rd way to do the JSON validation and create a custom report out of it, that is moderately elegant and not clumsy as writing two parsers (one of which parses the exception)?

Please also note that my JSON files can easily have 200+ fields, so writing a custom deserializer field-by-field is probably not an option.

I would like to get some advises on this, as I can't really find a reasonable way to do this.